# Restart 2008 Server using PowerShell CIM

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008, restart, cim

I can't seem to find a way to reboot a remote computer using CIM for a 2008 server.  All I have found was `Restart-PcsvDevice` but this doesn't work for 2008 servers.  Is there a way to use CIM to reboot 2008 servers?  I have to use CIM because of the DCOM protocol that is needed for my network.

Comment: Have you tried the [Restart-Computer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/restart-computer?view=powershell-6) cmdlet?

Comment: `Restart-Computer` doesn't offer the use of CIM as far as I can tell.

Comment: Why does the use of DCOM prevent you from using WinRM as well?

Answer (score 1):

I fail to see why the use of DCOM in your network would prevent you from also using WinRM, but whatever. If you must use WMI/CIM for this you can do so by invoking the `Reboot` method of the [`Win32_OperatingSystem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-operatingsystem) class on the remote host:

```
Invoke-CimMethod -Computer someserver -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Method Reboot
```

Note that the CIM cmdlets were introduced with PowerShell v3, which does not ship with Windows Server 2008 or 2008 R2, so you may need to use `Invoke-WmiMethod` instead, or [upgrade](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/06/02/weekend-scripter-install-powershell-3-0-on-windows-7/) to PowerShell v3 or newer.